# Best of breed Memcache Solutions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

Looking around the web I see a number of plugins and patterns for using memcached in rails. I'm working on a new project and am wondering what the best of breed solutions are. Google turns up a lot of older results, which I'm not sure are the latest and best ways of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

We have had great success with the cache-money plugin, which provides transparent write-thru and read-thru caching solution.

http://magicscalingsprinkles.wordpress.com/2008/12/11/introducing-cache-money/

Comment: Thanks, that looks great, now how about for cases that cache money doesn't cover (fragments, joins, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Garantia Data's Memcached Cloud](http://garantiadata.com/memcached) under heavy-load and it has performed well. Their dashboard gives useful insight to cache read/write activity and latency. If running on Amazon, Garantia offers a access across Amazon's east coast backplane for performance and reduced transmission costs. The only gem I have found that works with their service is Evan's [memcached gem](https://github.com/evan/memcached). Dalli gem is not an option yet (July 2013) because Garantia has not implemented support for the Memcached's binary protocol.

Comment: Update: Redis Labs' (formerly Garantia Data) Memcached ☁ fully supports the binary  protocol (i.e. SASL authentication) so any gem and client can work against it.